# IndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've got an error I hope you can help me solve.

I'm returning a String, seperated by ':' from a method getdata();
Everything works fine on the emulator, but when running the app on my device, the method returns an empty string and I get an error: IndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2.`

Code:

```
    Databaseengine info = new Databaseengine(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getdata();
    info.close();
    String[] values = null;

    values = data.split(":");

    tvans1.setText(values[4]);
    tvans2.setText(values[5]);
    tvans3.setText(values[6]);
    tvans4.setText(values[7]);
```

The method looks like this:

```
public String getdata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String [] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY, KEY_QUESTION, KEY_ANSWER, KEY_ALTONE, KEY_ALTTWO, KEY_ALTTHREE, KEY_ALTFOUR };

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null , null , null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 1");
    String result = "";
    //The cursor will be looking for these columns:
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iCat = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CATEGORY);
    int iQuiz = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUESTION);
    int iAns = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANSWER);
    int iAlt01 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALTONE);
    int iAlt02 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALTTWO);
    int iAlt03 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALTTHREE);
    int iAlt04 = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALTFOUR);


    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + ":"
        + c.getString(iCat) + ":" + c.getString(iQuiz) + ":" 
        + c.getString(iAns) + ":" + c.getString(iAlt01) + ":" 
        + c.getString(iAlt02) + ":" + c.getString(iAlt03) + ":"
        + c.getString(iAlt04) + "\n";

    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```

Please help me, before I go mental here :-)

Comment: at least post the content of the String data

Comment: Add a printout of `data` and see how many `:` it contains

Comment: What is your `info.getDate()` returning? Print it and see.

Comment: do you know what's the value of `values`?

Comment: something is missing because in the posted code, there is no use of 2 as an index, which the error indicates.

Comment: Show the value of data and staktrace.

Comment: add `Log.i("Test", Arrays.toString(values));` after split statement, see in logcat how many values are actually there.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the length of the resulting array after splitting.

To ask for an index no. 7, length must be at least 8 elements:

```
if (values.length > 7) { ..do your work.. } else { ..throw exception.. }
```

The different behavior you're getting on emulator/device must be related to distinct data being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

i am Not Sure But give it a try with this

```
 values = data.split("\\:");
```

instead of

```
 values = data.split(":");
```